# Adding git repository using terminal

Tags: git, github

I'm studying managing [git](/questions/tagged/git) system, but actually need a set of instructions, how exactly could i add a repository to my [github](/questions/tagged/github) account (through terminal)? That may sound obvious for many of you, but I'm struggling in attempts to figure that out by my own.

What I want to do is:

1. login to github (via terminal, enter my account details)
2. create a repo (in my git account folder)
3. push files from my local repository to that newly created repository (upload existing projects in it)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And where is the answer? The pointed question doesn't have it, or i am blind

Comment: Toumash I agree... But I suppose that is obvious for everyone except me.

Comment: You'll need to read https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ and use it with cURL http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: It will be something like `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  '{
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "description": "This is your first repository",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": false,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_downloads": true
}' https://api.github.com/user/repos`   but with Authentication

Comment: Thank you again, that's helpfull )) now I got it